# how to receive data from ESP32 to flutter app using bluetooth_serial

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working on a project which is basically showing the Realtime readings from firebase database that are being uploaded by ESP32. I am plotting an ECG graph in the app and the delays are terrible( uploading values to firebase). I want to shift the app to Bluetooth and did some research and found Bluetooth Serial for flutter.. I can connect to a Bluetooth device but I don't know how to receive data from this device. any help would be appreciated. I have 0 knowledge of implementing Bluetooth as I am new to Flutter.

I am using this : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial

currently I am using firebase Realtime Database for fetching values but the delays are huge due to internet delays. here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

whenever this ECG values changes in the firebase, the graph plots. I want to shift this graph to Bluetooth.

Comment: DO you have any specific problem? By the way, the ESP32 is capable of Bluetooth Low Energy, but flutter_bluetooth_serial uses Bluetooth Classic which is not compatible. You need to use something like https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue

Comment: im just printing the values from esp32 using BT_print() .. i think i have to use bluetooth classic i guess?

Comment: You can use Bluetooth classic if you want. Maybe this tutorial helps you: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-bluetooth-classic-arduino-ide/

Comment: thanks but this link does not have anything related to receiving data in flutter app ..

Comment: You previous comment made it seem that you have a problem on your ESP32 side, I'm sorry for misunderstanding. You should describe your problem in your question. https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial This is a flutter Bluetooth Classic library that also comes with examples for an arduino, which are very similar to your esp32 code

Comment: How are you taking your value for heart rate, are you using BT for it or do you store your value to firebase first and then retrieve it from DB?
I am also implementing heart rate in my app but i am not sure how do I show my value to my app?

Comment: https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial
and for ur problem on package, maybe this could help you out

Comment: i solved the problem by using Bluetooth classic and for the heart rate section.. i'm using firebase realtime db not BT

Comment: @NabiaSalman i've used Realtime db instead BT because i dont want to update the heartrate, temperature and spo2 on every second . There is a delay. I am basically designing a healthcare monitoring system that can monitor all these vital signs and i am almost done with it. let me know if you guyz need help :)

Comment: @M.Kotzjan thanks bro